# Mongodb aggregate multilevels

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to count documents containing 
  { date, direction, procedure } e.g
  {'Dec 12', 'West', 'Up' }

and I want output: foreach date, foreach direction, count each procedure type

```
Dec 12
    North Up 2  Down 3
    South Up 4  Down 17
    etc
```

It's fairly easy using javascript but I'd like to use mongodb if possible.  I can't get aggregate group to filter more than one level and I'm not sure if map_reduce would help.  I don't properly understand either.

I would appreciate a little guidance.  Thanks

---

Some detail:
  It's a schema-less collection but the interesting bits look like this:

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId(), "direction" : String, "procedure" : String, "date" : String, .... , "format" : "procedure" }
```

- direction: "North" | "East" | "South" | "West"
- procedure: "Arrive" | "Depart"
- date: "Mmm dd"
- ....  lots of other stuff

The output is not critical - it could be:

```
[ { date: "Mmm dd",
    direction:  { procedure: count, procedure: count },
    direction:  { procedure: count, ... },
       ....
   }

  { ... }

  ...
]
```

e.g:

```
[ { date: "Dec 12",
    "West": { "Arrive": 5, "Depart": 5 },
    "East": { "Arrive": 1, "Depart": 7 },
    ...
  },
  { date: ...},
  ...
]
```

The more I play with it the more I think it's a bit of a stretch - That could be good advise :-)

Comment: Hi. can you put the EXACT data schema in your DB (JSON style) and the exact format of the output you want (JSON style as well)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a solution for your aggregation pipeline:

```
[{
    '$group': {
        '_id': {
            'date': '$date',
            'direction': '$direction',
            'procedure': '$procedure'
        },
        'count': {'$sum': 1}
    }
},
{
    '$group': {
        '_id': '$_id.date',
        'directions': {
            '$push': {
                'direction': '$_id.direction',
                'procedure': '$_id.procedure',
                'count': '$count'
            }
        }
    }
}]
```

Giving the following result:

```
{
    _id: "Dec 12",
    directions: [
        { "direction": "North", "procedure": "Arrive", "count": 5},
        { "direction": "North", "procedure": "Depar", "count": 3},
        { "direction": "South", "procedure": "Arrive", "count": 1},
        ...
    ]
},
...
```

### Explanation

Basically what you are asking for is a count for each `(date, direction, procedure)` tuple. You just want it to be a little reorganized, and more precisely: grouped by date with for each date all possible `(direction, procedure)` couples, and the corresponding count.

So we are exactly doing this:

- first `$group` stage in the pipeline groups by unique `(date, direction, procedure)`, putting them in the `_id` field, and counting occurences; at this stage the output is:

  [{
      _id: {
          date: "Dec 12",
          direction: "North",
          procedure: "Depar"
      },
      count: 4
  },
  ...
  ]
- second `$group` stage just re-groups the results by date pushing other fields (which are embedded in a document at the `_id` field, as result of the previous stage) into an array at the new `directions` field, as `(direction, procedure, count)` tuples with the same date.

Comment: No, it doesn't compile.   Shame!  _id is an expression so it croaks building an object.  If I change brackets to () it compiles but it doesn't seem to understand $_id.thing.

Comment: Sorry I corrected the little typo error I did with the `_id` keys for `group` operators. I still cannot try it, sorry... I'll do so asap

Comment: wow, that's genius.  It just works.  Now I have to understand how it works.  Many thanks.

Comment: @nottledim Cool! Edited the answer with an explanation on how it works, if needed.